# Google Map V2 not working for me . Any sample?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have used many samples of **Google map V2**, and i have followed all the things which are necessary for this. But still having problem, only map view is showing and my current location is not being displayed on my **emulator**.

I have already created my system MD 5 key and API key from API console and used the SHA 1 key in manifest. But still having problem.

So please help me.

My Source Code :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.googlev2.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = fm.getMap();

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
    Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title("My Office"));

   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

  }
```

And activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

And AndroidManifest.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.googlev2.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <permission 
    android:name="com.googlev2.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature">
    </permission>

    <uses-permission 
    android:name="com.googlev2.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <!-- <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDciL7-T3BphxGv2q-A77vNrcyJQ_sTrgI"/> -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.googlev2.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <!--   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBDUb-4cOSTeeH3XqVQHwzXL2bT0aAM2h8"/>

        -->

         <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDiLovJFMLKEZkI5Ijtl0fKA-qApScD_Pk"/>


  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try it on real device

Comment: Can you tell us more info? Show us code you have already?

Comment: @Android Help check http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html and http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html

Comment: are u sure u r using map v2 ? because now it is part of google play service so it is tricky to implement on emulator.

Comment: http://raghunandankavi.blogspot.in/2013/04/google-map-api-v2-on-android.html. part 1. http://raghunandankavi.blogspot.in/2013/04/google-map-api-v2.html part 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your manifest file is correct Try this man

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraTargetLat="33.41662287712097"
    map:cameraTargetLng="35.21843892856462"
    map:cameraZoom="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In MainActivity.java onCreate()

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    GoogleMap mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097))
    .title("My Office"));

}
```

Here is the result on my phone
[image]

Comment: Am trying your code, it showing unfortunatly stop,  i think it will run on emulator

Comment: This tutorial is working or not try please http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/

Comment: You need to use a real device not a emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you add Activate the Google Maps Android API v2 in your Google APIs Console more details can be view in this link[How to Integrate Google map v2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

Comment: ya am sure to activate Google Maps Android API v2 in your Google APIs Console. And also follow this tutorial too. You can send me any sample. in which i will change api key and that show my current location. Send me on android.developer20@gmail.com

Comment: i had the same issue , i think your issue can be solved using above method

Comment: which method you are saying?

Comment: [chek this](www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

#### The keys to a working Google Maps v2 are

1. Add the v4 Support library (for older devices) and `google-play-services.jar` to your project.
2. Import the google-play-services_lib dummy project as a dependent project. It contains the very important `res/` directory with all the localized resources.
3. Make sure you created a keystore and key and that you are signing your APK with it. If you are using a debug keystore you need to add that to the [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).
4. Test on an Android device NOT the emulator. Google Play Services are not available on the emulator and you will not get a map. You get a white screen in the emulator IIRC.
5. Check that your AndroidManifest.xml has all the important entries - OpenGL 2, Meta-Key with your key, the permissions, etc.

Comment: Thank you i think my mistake is running on emulator .

Comment: Please solve my poblem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535454/facebook-sdk-integration-in-my-app

Answer (score 0):

After your meta-data that contains the api key you need to add the following lines

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

I suggest you to prove the genymotion emulator that is 20x times better than the default one. Here you can find the instructions to set it correctly:

[How do you install Google frameworks (Play, Accounts, etc.) on a Genymotion virtual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831990/how-do-you-install-google-frameworks-play-accounts-etc-on-a-genymotion-virtu/20013322#20013322)