# Error android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-maps-v2

i am following  tutorial for using google maps api v2 .i am facing an error 
error logs are

```
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.rtesh.onemore/org.rtesh.onemore.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1712)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at org.rtesh.onemore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     ... 11 more
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:395)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     ... 20 more
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.rtesh.onemore-1.apk]
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:385)
05-15 00:08:18.415: E/AndroidRuntime(4547):     ... 23 more
```

my MainActivity class is

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();

    if (map!=null){
      Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
          .title("Hamburg"));
      Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(KIEL)
          .title("Kiel")
          .snippet("Kiel is cool")
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
              .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    }

  }
```

}

and activity_main.xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i gave appropriate permissions in maifest class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.rtesh.onemore"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<permission
        android:name="org.rtesh.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.org.rtesh.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.rtesh.onemore.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

i referenced the google play service library why i am facing this error ??please some one help 
and please point the major differences between google maps version1 and 2!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to replace your layout with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You need to use the `SupportMapFragment` for API under 11 !

*In your MainActivity (or in each activity you want to put the v2 map) you must extend FragmentActivity or Activity either you want to use SupportMapFragment or just MapFragment. Use MapFragment class only if you are targeting API 12 and above. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment. It's a subtle difference but it makes the error.*

EDIT:

Please change your code in FragmentActivity:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
```

Understand the concept. Since you are targeting lower android versions where fragments are not supported, you need to use a support library that takes care of your fragments. So wherever you are using fragments make sure you are importing a fragment from `support` library.

Comment: for using SupportMapFragment op will need to add support library as well

Comment: he needs to add support library android-support-v4.jar.i am not talking about using it

Comment: in sdk manager i downloaded google play services then reference this library but still i am facing the error

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta make the changes as suggested in the answer. Also add support library by downloading the same http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Downloading

Comment: yeah but assuming that he has added it already (if we see the title) otherwise he would have got a compile time error referencing a support lib without actually adding. But he's getting a run time exception. so I believe he must have already added the lib

Comment: Hey ritesh are u pointing to support lib as I have mentioned above in xml file?

Comment: yes only the change i did in my code is changing activity_main.xml to <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: i got your point but facing a compile error can not cast fragment to SupportMapFragment .how to resolve this i changed the layout accordingly .please reply last time

Comment: got it use getSupportFragmentManger instead of getFragmentManager function

Answer (score 1):

First, like the other responders to this post you should change the minimum Android SDK level to at least 11

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
```

Here is a working example that I made yesterday.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:cameraTargetLat="33.41662287712097"
map:cameraTargetLng="35.21843892856462"
map:cameraZoom="4"/>

</LinearLayout>In MainActivity.java onCreate()
```

In MainActivity.java onCreate()

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097))
.title("My Office"));

}
```

To see my screenshot of the result of the code see my answer in this post. gl hf! 
[Google Map V2 not working for me . Any sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535136/google-map-v2-not-working-for-me-any-sample/16535888#16535888)

Comment: Can you explain, why we need to have minSdkVersion to 11?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195631/google-maps-v2-on-android-devices-with-minsdk-below-11

Comment: Yes but as per Mark's comment what i understood abd the fact is that android support lib is specifically designed to support features that are not available for older android version.

Comment: And this fellow is already using support library so he does not have to increase his minsdk req. He just needs to import classes from support lib n not android lib

Answer (score 0):

Your min sdk is 8. You will need to add support library for api versions below 12

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

So for backward compatibality you need add support library

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment "
```

Since you din't add support library you got classcastexception

To add support library check the link below

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

For downloading the support fragment

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Downloading

For more information check the link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment

Check the line just above the heading developers guide.

For more information on map api v2 check the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 0):

public class SearchOffer extends FragmentActivity {

```
GoogleMap gmpSearchOfferMap;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.search_offers);

        if (gmpSearchOfferMap == null) {
            gmpSearchOfferMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.gmpOfferMap)).getMap();
        }

        if (gmpSearchOfferMap != null) {
            gmpSearchOfferMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            gmpSearchOfferMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(
                    true);
            gmpSearchOfferMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            gmpSearchOfferMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}