# Android - VerifyError when insantiating Fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-2.3-gingerbread

I recently launched an app on the Play Store and I had a crash come in that I can't reproduce (but the user can). It's on a GT-I9000 (Samsung Galaxy S, international) with android version 2.3.3.

I get a VerifyError when a Fragment is instantiated. I'm using ActionBarSherlock. Attached is the code snippet and stack trace.

Any ideas on how I can dig into this deeper and/or possible cause?

Thanks.

Stack Trace:

```
0   java.lang.VerifyError: com.jailbase.mobile_app.ui.HomeFragment
1       at com.jailbase.mobile_app.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:36)
2       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
3       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
4       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
5       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
6       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
7       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
8       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
9       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
13        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
14        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code Snippet:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        mHomeFrag= (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home);

        if (mHomeFrag == null) {
            mHomeFrag=new HomeFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.home, mHomeFrag)
                    .commit();
        }
```

The error happens on this line:

```
mHomeFrag=new HomeFragment();
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/16550877/1306419

Comment: Look higher up in the logs for the actual verify error which will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: where you able to solve it?

Comment: I don't recall, however Jack Wharton's comment above is relevant.

Comment: @Jake Wharton dont talk if u can not solve this problem